# Add firewall rule in front of a Google Cloud Load Balancer

Tags: firewall, google-cloud-platform

I have a Load Balancer on Google Cloud.

I want to setup a simple firewall rule that will restrict access to the Load Balancer from specific ip.

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, by adding [Google Cloud Armor](https://cloud.google.com/armor).

Create a security policy. Add rules to the security policy. Assign the security policy to HTTP Load Balancer. If your goal is to only allow traffic from specific addresses, be sure to change the default rule to DENY.

[Configuring Google Cloud Armor security policies](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/configure-security-policies)

Cloud Armor makes it very easy to create a rule based upon IP address match.

[image]

Comment: I managed to almost achieve what I want using VPC firewall. The only problem is that when I block the external - for some reason it also blocks the internal from the load-balancer.

Comment: @Dani - You cannot use a VPC firewall to block access to the load balancer. When the load balancer connects to your VM, the VPC firewall sees the load balancer's IP address and not the client's IP address. The client's IP address is stored in the HTTP header **X-Forwarded-For** and VPC firewalls do not process HTTP headers.